# Further Problem on Tangents Requiring the Use of Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Show that the tangent to the curve  $y = x^3 - 2x$,  at the point with $x$-coordinate $a$ meets the curve again at a point with $x$-coordinate $-2a$.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Are you able to set up the equation of the tangent line?

Answer (score 1):

we have $$y(x)=x^3-2x$$ then $$y'(x)=3x^2-2$$ then $$y'(a)=3a^2-2$$ and the tangent line has the form
$$y(x)=(3a^2-2)x+n$$ for $x=a$ we get $$y(a)=a^3-2a$$
and you can compute $n$:
$$a^3-2a=(3a^2-2)a+n$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

- set up the equation of the tangent line at $(a,f(a))$;
- find the points of intersection between this line and $y=x^3-2x$.

**Hint**: remember that you already know that $x=a$ will be a solution; this may help in finding the other one.